# Find The number of sides of triangle

Tags: algorithm

I am giving a Array `A` consists of integer, I have to choose any two integer from array A and any third integer from range `[L,R]` , such that all three integer forms a valid triangle.

I have to find the number of integer in range [L,R] which can be used to form a valid triangle, by choosing any two values from array A.

I know if i know two sides then third side must be range `a-b<x<a+b` 
where a and b are any two integer from A.

How to find the number of valid integer in [L,R] in `O(N)  N= Size of A` time.
L and R and be very large upto `10^20`

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) website, as it's about algorithms, not implementation-specific problems. Regarding your question: looks like you're referring to some competitive programming-like problem, please provide a link to the original problem. Also, I highly doubt this problem is solvable in linear time if `A` is unsorted in the first place.

Comment: I assume you're talking about finding possible lengths for the triangle sides?

Comment: Number of integer in range `[L R]` which i can chooses as third side

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes looping in O(N^2) getting the value of `x` but too slow

Comment: @yeputons when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Thank you. Do you have any good template for that kind of message in mind?

Comment: ooooo @yeputons here :o sorry mods for irrelevant comment

Comment: @yeputons I found the link to the original problem https://www.codechef.com/FEB17/problems/MAKETRI but note that the contest is active until Feb 13

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Thanks, I almost posted an answer (which is correct as I passed the question on codechef). O(N lg N) solution is possible and I will post it after the contest has finished

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, complete enumeration will yield an efficient solution by the following argument. The maximum number of possible solutions occurs in the case where *any* selection of elements of `A` yields a consistent choice of side lengths for a triangle. Such an input, for instance, would be an input of `N` times the value `1`. However, the number of triples chosen from `A` can be bounded by

```
(n choose 3) =  n!/(3!(n-3))
             =  n!/(6(n-3)!)
             =  (1/6)*(n-2)*(n-1)*n
             <= n^3
```

(where `choose` is meant to denote the binomial coefficient) which is a polynomial number of choices. Any choice can be checked for validity in constant time, as only 3 values are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Now the contest has ended, so here is my way to solve it in the contest.

---

The problem is asking how many number `x` in `[L,R]`can form triangle with  any pair `(a_i, a_j)` in `A`.

Naive method is to brute all pairs which is `O(N^2 * (R-L+1))` = `O(N^2 * (R-L))`

But indeed, we do not need to test all `O(N^2)` pairs, we only need to test `O(N)` pairs **IF** `A` is sorted, namely, all adjacent pair `(a_i-1, a_i)` for i > 0

---

Why? Because in sorted `A`:

If there is some pair `(a_j, a_i)` where `a_j < a_i and j != i-1`, which can form triangle with `x`

Then `(a_i-1, a_i)` must form a triangle with `x` too:

> 1. `a_i-1 + a_i > a_j + a_i > x`
> 2. `x + a_i-1 > x + a_j > a_i`
> 3. `x + a_i > x + a_i-1 > a_j`

Therefore checking all `(a_i-1, a_i)` is sufficient, this is the first core idea to solve this problem.

---

So now we have a `O(NlgN + N*(R-L+1))` = `O(N*(R-L))` algorithm.

For the original contest problem, it is still too slow as `R-L+1` is as large as 10^18, so we need another tricks.

Note that actually by the triangle inequality, for a pair `(a_i-1, a_i)`, indeed we can find a range of `x` which can form triangle with this pair:

`a_i-1 + a_i > x > a_i - a_i-1 (By above 1 & 2)`

For example, (4,5) can form triangle with all 1 < `x` < 9

So instead of iterating all `x` in `[L,R]`, we try to find range of `x` for each pair, which can be done in `O(N)` as we know the range for `x` of a pair in `O(1)`. Beware that `x` must fall in the range of `[L,R]`.

After that we have `O(N)` ranges  / segments of `x` which then we can union them and the size of the result set is the desired answer.

Union `O(N)` segments can be done easily in `O(N)` as well, I leave you as a homework :)

---

Combine both tricks, the algorithm is `O(N lg N + N  + N)` = `O(N lg N)`